# Is there a SUBSTR alternative in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to extract the the different sub-strings within one string. The I want different strings for every string divided by the dash (-) symbol.

I have tried using the SUBSTR position function. It does not work since sometimes there are 4 chars in the second sub string, therefore, the 3rd sub string is not correct.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(STR, INSTR (STR, '-', -1)+ 1)

STR = F-123-A123-B12 or F-1234-A123-B12
```

- I am trying to get a query that will give me F.
- I need another query that will give me 123 or 1234 if there are 4 chars
- I need another query to get me A123
- I need another query to get B12

I was thinking there would be a regex function that I could use. I could not find one.

Comment: Did you try `regexp_substr()`?

Comment: I have not. I will try doing that.

Comment: Google "oracle regular expressions". [First hit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions. `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` will work (and are faster):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( str ) AS
  SELECT 'F-123-A123-B12'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F-1234-A123-B12' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( str, 1,              delimiter1 - 1              ) AS substr1,
       SUBSTR( str, delimiter1 + 1, delimiter2 - delimiter1 - 1 ) AS substr2,
       SUBSTR( str, delimiter2 + 1, delimiter3 - delimiter2 - 1 ) AS substr3,
       SUBSTR( str, delimiter3 + 1                              ) AS substr4
FROM   (
  SELECT str,
         INSTR( str, '-', 1, 1 ) AS delimiter1,
         INSTR( str, '-', 1, 2 ) AS delimiter2,
         INSTR( str, '-', 1, 3 ) AS delimiter3
  FROM   test_data
) s
```

**Output**:

> ```
> SUBSTR1 | SUBSTR2 | SUBSTR3 | SUBSTR4
> :------ | :------ | :------ | :------
> F       | 123     | A123    | B12    
> F       | 1234    | A123    | B12
> ```

If you do want to use regular expressions, then there is no need for a hierarchical query:

**Query 2**:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '[^-]+', 1, 1 ) AS substr1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '[^-]+', 1, 2 ) AS substr2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '[^-]+', 1, 3 ) AS substr3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '[^-]+', 1, 4 ) AS substr4
FROM   test_data
```

*(Output as Query 1 above.)*

**Query 3**

If you don't know how many delimited values there will be and want to parse them all to rows then you *still* don't need to use (slow) regular expressions or hierarchical queries and can just use a recursive sub-query factoring clause with simple string functions (and it works with zero-width/`NULL` sub-strings between delimiters):

```sql
WITH substr_bounds ( str, idx, startidx, endidx ) AS (
  SELECT str,
         1,
         1,
         INSTR( str, '-', 1 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT str,
         idx + 1,
         endidx + 1,
         INSTR( str, '-', endidx + 1 )
  FROM   substr_bounds
  WHERE  endidx > 0
)
SELECT str,
       idx,
       CASE
       WHEN endidx = 0
       THEN SUBSTR( str, startidx )
       ELSE SUBSTR( str, startidx, endidx - startidx )
       END AS substr
FROM   substr_bounds
ORDER BY str, idx
```

**Output**:

> ```
> STR             | IDX | SUBSTR
> :-------------- | --: | :-----
> F-123-A123-B12  |   1 | F     
> F-123-A123-B12  |   2 | 123   
> F-123-A123-B12  |   3 | A123  
> F-123-A123-B12  |   4 | B12   
> F-1234-A123-B12 |   1 | F     
> F-1234-A123-B12 |   2 | 1234  
> F-1234-A123-B12 |   3 | A123  
> F-1234-A123-B12 |   4 | B12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2f030e7e05af1dd29d9baae6aac87289)*

Comment: I was able to get it to work using your example. Thank you all for your quick guidance on this issue.

Comment: @HarshBilodiya If an answer has solved your problem then you can accept it with the check mark below the voting buttons to the left of the answer. This lets other users know that your problem has been solved and which solution worked for you. Comments, while nice, tend to get deleted unless they actually supplement the answer.

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'F-123-A123-B12' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, level) result
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '-') + 1;

RESULT
--------------
F
123
A123
B12

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string could have a NULL element, use this format to handle it (Note list element 2 is NULL), else you risk the following elements being returned in the wrong positions:

```
with test (col) as 
      (select 'F--A123-B12' from dual)
    select regexp_substr(col, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, level, null, 1) result
    from test
    connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '-') + 1;

RESULT     
-----------
F          

A123       
B12        

4 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with newest Node 17.3.1 where "substr" function is obsolete and I replace it with "substring" instead and it is the nearest and simplest alternative.